# Loop through cells of all Excel Worksheets to generate one XML file

Tags: excel, xml, vba, loops

I have 10 sheets. I wrote some code to go through all the data inside a sheet and create an XML file as an output.

I have to click the button each time at each sheet and then I have 10 different XML files. I want one button in one sheet, let's call it Description, to go through all my sheets and create one file with all the XML data.

I tried to use a for each loop. Instead of reading all the sheets, it reads only the first sheet for many times.

```vb
Sub XMLTextdatei()

 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim loLetzteZ As Long, loLetzteS As Long, I As Long
 Dim rBereich As Range, rng As Range
 Dim sTagO As String, sTagC As String, sTagOEnd As String, sTagCStart As String
 Dim sZeile As String
 Dim strPfad As String
 Dim strText As String
  
 sTagO = "<"
 sTagOEnd = "/>"
 sTagC = ">"
 sTagCStart = "</"
 
 Set sht = ActiveSheet

 For Each sht In Worksheets 
 
 loLetzteZ = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 loLetzteS = sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 Set rBereich = sht.Range("A2:" & Cells(loLetzteZ, loLetzteS).Address)
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
 sZeile = ""
 strPfad = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Classification" & "_" & Format(Time, "hhmmss") & ".xml"
 
  'zeile für zeile

  For Each rng In rBereich.Rows

    With rng
  
        'spalte für spalte
        For I = 1 To .Columns.Count
          
          If I = 1 Then
             sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & Cells(1, I) & "=""" & .Cells(1, I) & """" & sTagC
          Else
              If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, I)) Then
                sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & Cells(1, I) & sTagOEnd
              Else
                sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & Cells(1, I) & sTagC
                sZeile = sZeile & .Cells(1, I)
                sZeile = sZeile & sTagCStart & Cells(1, I) & sTagC
              End If
          End If
          sZeile = sZeile & vbCrLf
        Next
        'sZeile = sZeile & "</" & " " & ">"
        sZeile = sZeile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Call InDateiSchreiben(strPfad, sZeile, True)
        sZeile = ""
    End With
  Next
 Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: *it reads only the first sheet for many times* That's because you binded the same range. Loot at `Set rBereich = sht.Range("A2:" & Cells(loLetzteZ, loLetzteS).Address)` and then you do `For Each rng In rBereich.Rows` so you loop all the time trough same cells in same range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will traverse all worksheets.  You need to use your sheet variable in the loop, instead of just setting it outside the loop

```
Dim oCurSheet As Worksheet
For Each oCurSheet In Me.Worksheets
   oCurSheet.(Whatever you are doing with it)
Next
```

Edit:
I've gotten rid of rBereich in the for each collection in favor of going to the sheet. Also removed setting sht to active sheet, as the assigning is done in the for loop.

You need to use the variables in your for each loops where applicable within the loops.  In the updated code you'll see sht.Cells(1,I) used to reference the current Sheet's Columns.

The additional Empty tags were due to your If IsEmpty statement, if there was nothing in the tag you were adding < (blank) </>.  So I've commented the line out, if you need a value to illustrate blanks then you would want to do it simlar to the else statement, and put a value say NA where the .cells(1,I) is.

```
 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim loLetzteZ As Long, loLetzteS As Long, I As Long
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim sTagO As String, sTagC As String, sTagOEnd As String, sTagCStart As String
 Dim sZeile As String
 Dim strPfad As String
 Dim strText As String
  
 sTagO = "<"
 sTagOEnd = "/>"
 sTagC = ">"
 sTagCStart = "</"
 

    For Each sht In Me.Worksheets
        loLetzteZ = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        loLetzteS = sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
        For Each rng In sht.Range("A2:" & sht.Cells(loLetzteZ, loLetzteS).Address).Rows
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
            sZeile = ""
            strPfad = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Classification" & "_" & Format(Time, "hhmmss") & ".xml"
            With rng
  
            'spalte für spalte
            For I = 1 To .Columns.Count
              
              If I = 1 Then
                 sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & sht.Cells(1, I) & "=""" & .Cells(1, I) & """" & sTagC
              Else
                  If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, I)) Then
                    ' No Tag if empty
                    'sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & sht.Cells(1, I) & sTagOEnd
                  Else
                    sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & sht.Cells(1, I) & sTagC
                    sZeile = sZeile & .Cells(1, I)
                    sZeile = sZeile & sTagCStart & sht.Cells(1, I) & sTagC
                  End If
              End If
              sZeile = sZeile & vbCrLf
            Next
        'sZeile = sZeile & "</" & " " & ">"
        sZeile = sZeile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        'MsgBox (sZeile)
        Call InDateiSchreiben(strPfad, sZeile, True)
        sZeile = ""
    End With
  Next
 Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP wants to know why the loops checks always same cells.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have tried this one, but now I have the problem, that it creates a lot of unnecessary tags. For example see here: 

```
<csvattTemplate>description</csvattTemplate>
<csvnameSpace>false</csvnameSpace>
<csvname>This is a Type Test</csvname>
<csvcontainerDomain>New Type.</csvcontainerDomain>
<csvtypeParent/>
</csvBeginTypeDefView/>
</>
</>
</>
</>
</>
</>
</>
</>
</>
</>
```

Comment: I forgot your associated variables, I had just edited it in.  Probably got extra tags because it was using variables that were set for the first page for your max row & column.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I have tried it, but it is still not working. 
It has created too many files that also had missing data. 
Btw. VBA throws me an error for the command Me.Worksheets: Error in the compilation. Illegal use of the keyword me

Comment: Sorry, I have no reference to what data might be missing, does it have to do with the blank fields I commented out?  Just `worksheets` should be fine.  And again no reference but I'm assuming your InDateiSchreiben() function is what is creating your file?  If so I'm not sure exactly how it works but you would have to make sure it makes sense at that location within the context of the loops.  ie. does it append to the file or does it create new files?  Does it make more sense to compile the entire xml first and then export it?  etc..

Comment: Hey Joseph, your code works properly after I have uncomment this line: 'sZeile = sZeile & sTagO & sht.Cells(1, I) & sTagOEnd
And deleted the Me. in For Each sht In Me.Worksheets. 


Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the save as XML of Excel ?

You could use use your code to reunite the data into a new sheet and then use the saveas xml format.

If you use the xml 2003 you do not need to set any xml mapping, for higher versions allow you to create your own XML mapping (see developper ruler).